# How to calculate the inverse factorial of a real number?

Tags: algorithm, math, factorial

Is there some way to calculate the inverse factorials of real numbers?

For example - [`1.5 ! = 1.32934039`](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=1.5!)

Is there some way to obtain `1.5` back if I have the value `1.32934039`?

I am trying

> `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma^(-1)[1.32934039]`

but that is a fail.

Comment: FYI this doesn’t work with natural numbers either. I.e. the Γ function has no inverse in general.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: has no inverse? I dint understand. There should be  *some* inverse.

Comment: I think you might want to ask your question on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @Robin Day: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652536) says that mathoverflow.net is for research level math and such questions are actually suited better for this site.

Comment: @Lazer: If you consider http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gamma(x) you'll see that the Gamma function is not injective on \R, i.e. there are some y-values that are obtained for several x-values. But if we restrict ourselves to x > 2 (say), then there is no problem.

Comment: Eventually the place for this question should be http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics but that's not up and running yet.

Comment: @Lazer: You don't appear to be asking help on how to code something. Rather you're asking for help with a mathematical algorithm. Hence I would point you at mathoverflow. Maybe you should try both places?!

Comment: @Robin Day: mathoverflow.com is for research level maths, not high-school level. I don't think there is anywhere better than stackoverflow.com for questions about mathematical algorithms.

Comment: There might not be a better site than stackoverflow to ask the question but that still doesn't mean it is a good question for the stackoverflow site. One reason for stackoverflow's success is its dedication and restriction to coding questions.

Comment: replaced reverse with inverse.

Comment: @Mike: I would not call questions about the gamma function "high-school level"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using wolframalpha.com, you can ask for

```
Solve[Gamma[x+1]==1.32934039,x]
```

As mentioned in the comments, Gamma does not have a unique inverse.  True even when you are solving for a conventional factorial, e.g.

```
Solve[Gamma[x+1]==6,x]
```

yields several answers, of which one is 3.

Instead of using Gamma[] in WolframAlpha, you can also use Factorial[]:

```
Solve[Factorial[x]==6,x]
Solve[Factorial[x]==1.32934039,x]
```

Comment: "The convential factorial" is only defined on the natural numbers {0, 1, 2, ...}, and for this the only problem here is that 0! = 1!. (For instance, x! = 6 has only one root in the natural numbers, namely 3.)

Comment: @Andreas, OP is asking about a generalization of conventional factorials known as the gamma function.  This is implemented in Mathematica/WolphramAlpha as Gamma[x+1] or Factorial[x].  Give it a try.

Comment: Of course I know that. I am very well familiar with the Gamma function. But brainjam says that "Gamma does not have a unique inverse. True even when you are solving for a conventional factorial, e.g. Solve[Gamma[x+1]==6,x]
yields several answers, of which one is 3." This can be interpreted as if x! = 6 has several solutions on the natural numbers, which is false. The only solution is 3. Maybe it is just bad wording.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the clarification.  Sorry for implying you didn't know about Gamma, you probably know more about than I do.

Comment: Do anyone get some result for `Solve[Gamma[x+1]==2^1024,x]`? I am getting nothing.

Comment: @Lazer, nope, it fails silently.  I believe it's solving numerically, and that the big numbers in question are probably causing it to get lost (i.e. not converge on a solution).  2^1024 is in the ballpark of 170!, which is pretty big.

Comment: @Lazer Wolfram alpha calculates OK till 2^268. With 2^269 it fails silently (MBS: manual binary search :) )

Answer (score 5):

David Cantrell gives a good approximation of Γ<sup>-1</sup>(n) on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171104030158/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=342551&tstart=0):

```
k = the positive zero of the digamma function, approximately 1.461632
c = Sqrt(2*pi)/e - Γ(k), approximately 0.036534
L(x) = ln((x+c)/Sqrt(2*pi))
W(x) = Lambert W function
ApproxInvGamma(x) = L(x) / W(L(x) / e) + 1/2
```

Answer (score 3):

For integers you can do:

```
i = 2
n = someNum
while (n != 1):
    n /= i
    i += 1
return (i==1 ? i : None)
```

The factorial for real numbers has no inverse. You say that "each function must have an inverse". That is incorrect. Consider the constant function `f(x)=0`. What is `f^-1(42)`? For a function to be inverse it must be **both** an **injection** and a **surjection**.

Comment: It should be `i = 1`, the division and increment should be swapped, and you can just return `i`.

Comment: He doesn't say "each function" (but maybe he edited it?).  But `Γ(x)` on `[2,∞)` is (unlike `f(x)=0`) injective.  There should be an inverse on at least that subdomain.

Comment: A: thanks, I understand the inverse concepts though. What I said was in context of the gamma function - because it appears that it is a one-one non-decreasing function, atleast for positive real numbers.

Comment: Thanks guy. The code in the ans seems having some typos. But i have based on it and implemented an effective algorithm.