# recursive factorial formula

Tags: java, recursion

I want to get an output that displays something like `1*2*3*4` but instead I get `4*3*2*1`
this is my code:

```
public static int fact(int n)

    {
        if(n ==1)
            return 1;
        else
            return n * fact(n-1);
    }

    public static int factorForm(int n)
    {
        System.out.print(n);
        if (n == 1)
            return 1;
        else
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            return n + '*' + factorForm(n-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `return n + '*' + factorForm(n-1);` is not doing what you think

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652536/reverse-factorial

Comment: `1*2*3*4 === 4*3*2*1` I don't get what's the problem.

Comment: Use pen and paper and follow the code with n = 4 and you'll find the reason.

Comment: @Leri That's not mulitplication. It's numbers separated by stars.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Oh, sorry, OP is outputting string. I should have looked at the code as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are calling fact(4)

Then you print

Then you call fact(3)

If you invert that you'll get what you want:

```
public class fact { 
  static int f(int n)
  {
    if (n ==1 )
    {
        System.out.print(1);
        return 1;
    }
    int ret= (n * f(n-1));
    System.out.print("*");
    System.out.print(n);
    return ret;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int ret=f(4);
    System.out.print("=");
    System.out.println(ret);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the output, `n` should be printed after making the recursive call:

```
public static int factorForm(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        System.out.print(1);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int rest = factorForm(n-1); // prints 1*2*...*n-1
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.print(n);
        return rest * n;
    }
}
```

The expression `n + '*' + factorForm(n-1)` performs integer addition, not multiplication or string concatenation. I changed it to perform multiplication. If the intention is to return the string that was printed, the return type and the type of `rest` should be changed to `String`, the return value in the base case should be `"1"`, and that expression should be changed to `rest + "*" + n`.

Answer (score 0):

Return after printing as below, more importantly understand how recursion works:

```
public static int factorForm(int n)
{        
    if (n == 1){
        System.out.print("1*");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {            
        int val = n * factorForm(n-1);            
        System.out.print(n + "*");
        return val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get like 1*2*3*4 result. i think you can do this. 
this is my code:

```
public static String fact(int n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("n must be int type and up 0");
    }
    else if (n == 1) {
        return "1";
    } else {
        return n + "*" + fact(n - 1);
    }
}

public static String factorForm(String str) {
    String [] arr = str.split("\\*");
    String [] newArr = new String[arr.length];
    String result = "";
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            newArr[arr.length - i - 1] = arr[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
            result += newArr[i] + (i != newArr.length - 1 ? "*" : "");
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

---

like this. you can get results what you get. may be complicated.

Comment: called method like this:factorForm(fact(5))