# Reverse factorial fun won't go beyond 170

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner at pyhon and I'm trying to reverse the factorial function.
The factorial of 5 is 120
And I want my code to take input 120 and be able to return 5
Here's my present code:

```
`from math import factorial
    def rf(f):
        d=2
        while f/factorial(d) != 1:
            if f/factorial(d) <= 1:
                 print("Entered number is not a factorial")
                 return
            d += 1
        return int(d)`
```

It can reverse the factorial upto 170.But when I enter the factorial of 171 the code gets into OverFlowError.
Is there a solution to my code?
or, a more reliable code to reverse factorial.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you format you code and post the traceback of the error (copy paste, no screenshot). Thank you. Also can you explain what you mean by reversing the factorial. See [mcve] for details.

Comment: A lot of ideas from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652536/reverse-factorial

Answer (score 4):

The immediate problem is that you're using floating-point math, and floating-point math has limited range:

```
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

(`170!` is smaller than this, but `171!` is larger.)

If you stick to integer math, you'll sidestep that problem since Python integers are only limited by the amount of available memory and so can grow much larger.

It's also worth noting that repeatedly calling `factorial()` is expensive.

If it were me, I'd do something like this:

```
def rf(f):
  n = 2
  while True:
    f, r = divmod(f, n)
    if r != 0:
      return None  # input isn't a factorial
    if f == 1:
      return n
    n += 1

print(rf(6))
print(rf(42))
print(rf(200896062499134299656951336898466838917540340798867777940435335160044860953395980941180138112097309735631594101037399609671032132186331495273609598531966730972945653558819806475064353856858157445040809209560358463319644664891114256430017824141796753818192338642302693327818731986039603200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000))
```

This divides the input by `2` then `3` then `4` etc until the result is `1`, while making sure that the remainder stays zero throughout.

I've used [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) to simultaneously compute the quotient and the remainder of each division step.

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you could explain what `divmod` does and how it is useful

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod - returns quotient and remainder of integer division

Comment: Well, I've seen the page. The answer is not complete without the explanation imo

Answer (score 0):

Though @NPE's solution is much cleaner and more efficient, you could use your original code with a small change to make it work: use floor division `//`, that returns integers, instead of normal division `/`:

```
from math import factorial

def rf(f):
    d=2
    while f//factorial(d) != 1:
        if f//factorial(d) <= 1:
            print("Entered number is not a factorial")
            return
        d += 1
    return int(d)

rf(factorial(171))
# 171
```